# Manage a dynamic site with FTP acess only

Tags: php, web, cpanel

Can I manage a dynamic website (contains some php scripts) with only a FTP account, because the admin of the site can't provide access to the CPanel interface.

Comment: Depends on what you need to manage. If you just need to make edits to PHP files, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you sure can. You won't be able to perform any admin tasks, but managing the PHP files won't be a problem.